# Why does my Review Button show 4 reviews but there are none?

Tags: support, review, top-bar

From time to time, my Review Button will show a number of reviews to consider, yet when I click on the button **fewer** (always fewer, never more) reviews are shown?  Sometimes the number resets to 0, sometimes the number increases, but the reviews in the queue are less and **are different to reviews done just previously**.

Looking at the **related questions**, the examples were either there were **no edits** or there is a **persistence** in the number of edits in the queue. Neither seem to be the same as my case where the number changes, but there is nothing in the queue, or the number remains the same, but there are different reviews in the queue. Coincidence in the latter seems possible but highly unlikely.

This also seems to happen in the middle of the night EST.

Is this an update problem or am I missing something else I should be doing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The review button shows the review total for all queues.

The number shown when you open a queue is the number of reviews available for you personally to action in that queue.

So the numbers don't add up if you have previously reviewed some items in the queues (as they are now no longer available for you to review).

Comment: That would suggest there is some sort of **lag** between **submitting a review** and the queue number **updating**?

Comment: No lag @Peter - see the dupe and its answer.

Comment: From the "dup" answer, it would seem that the reason I am shown 4 in the original queue, and after I edit 1, there are then only 2 to be reviewed, is because the third review was taken care of by someone(s) else? Wouldn't the system "checkout" all 4 of my reviews once I click on the Review Button?

Comment: @peter. I don't believe so, since you can stop reviewing after just 1 if you choose. And don't forget that reviews mostly require several reviewers (with exceptions like the dupe hammer and probably mods). The 3rd review bit is probably correct assuming the correct number of other reviewers took care of it before you got to it.

Comment: @Peter thing is, the number is not "your" reviews, i.e. how many items you can review, but the total number of reviews, without performing any checks. For example it also show posts you already voted to close outside the review, thus you can't review yourself.

Comment: That would explain a lot, I thought there might have been some algorithm that chose me to make certain "types'  of reviews based on my posting profile. Thanks